# Strange Wordpress 'The webpage cannot be found' error in Explorer Only

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer

I am getting a strange  'The webpage cannot be found' error  in my Wordpress 3.4.1 Blog. I have disabled all possible plug ins that could be the cluprit. This error only happens in Explorer and Opera but works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. This only happens in two sections under the Event Manager plugin but I even disabled that one but happens only in one content posting. The other strange item is this box randomly shows in each display so it is not fixed. Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction before I lose all my hair? I am not sure if I am allowed to post links in questions at stackoverflow.com

I managed to track down some generated code thanks to Debug Bar in Internet Explorer:

```
<html><head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ErrorPageTemplate.css">

    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

    <title>HTTP 400 Bad Request</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="errorPageStrings.js">
    </script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="httpErrorPagesScripts.js">
    </script>


</head><body onload="javascript:initHomepage(); expandCollapse('infoBlockID', true); initGoBack(); initMoreInfo('infoBlockID');">

    <table border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="730">

    <!-- Error title -->
        <tbody><tr>
            <td id="infoIconAlign" vAlign="top" rowSpan="2" width="60" align="left">
                <img id="infoIcon" alt="Info icon" src="info_48.png">
            </td>
            <td id="mainTitleAlign" vAlign="middle" width="*" align="left">
                <h1 id="mainTitle">The webpage cannot be found</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
            <!-- This row is for HTTP status code, as well as the divider-->
            <td id="http400Align" class="errorCodeAndDivider" align="right"><id id="http400">&nbsp;HTTP 400</id>
                <div class="divider"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>


    <!-- Error Body -->

    <!-- What you can do -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td id="likelyCausesAlign" vAlign="top" align="left">
                <h3 id="likelyCauses">Most likely causes:</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li id="causeErrorInAddress">There might be a typing error in the address.</li>
                    <li id="causeLinkOutOfDate">If you clicked on a link, it may be out of date.</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td id="whatToTryAlign" vAlign="top" align="left">
                <h2 id="whatToTry">What you can try:</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <!-- retype address -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td id="retypeAddressAlign" vAlign="middle" align="left">
                <h4>
                    <table>
                      <tbody><tr>
                          <td vAlign="top">
                              <img class="actionIcon" border="0" alt="" src="bullet.png">
                          </td>
                          <td vAlign="top">
                              <id id="retypeAddress">Retype the address.</id>
                          </td>
                      <tr>
                    </tr></tbody></table>
                </h4>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <!-- back to previous page -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td id="goBackAlign" vAlign="middle" align="left">
                <h4>
                    <table>
                      <tbody><tr>
                          <td vAlign="top">
                              <img class="actionIcon" border="0" alt="" src="bullet.png">
                          </td>
                          <td vAlign="top">
                              <span id="goBackContainer"><a href="javascript:history.back();">Go back to the previous page.</a></span><noscript id="goBack">Go back to the previous page.</noscript>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </h4>
            </td>
        </tr>


    <!-- top level domain-->
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td id="mainSiteAlign" vAlign="middle" align="left">
                <h4>
                    <table>
                      <tbody><tr>
                          <td vAlign="top">
                              <img class="actionIcon" border="0" alt="" src="bullet.png">
                          </td>
                          <td vAlign="top">
                              <id id="mainSite1">Go to </id><span id="homepageContainer"><noscript id="mainSite2">the main site</noscript><a href=""></a></span><id id="mainSite3">&nbsp;and look for the information you want.</id>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </h4>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <!-- InfoBlock -->
        <tr>
            <td id="infoBlockAlign" vAlign="top" align="right">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td id="moreInfoAlign" vAlign="middle" align="left">
                <h4>
                    <table>
                      <tbody><tr>
                          <td vAlign="top">
                              <a onclick="javascript:expandCollapse('infoBlockID', true); return false;" href="#"><img id="infoBlockIDImage" class="actionIcon" border="0" alt="More information" src="down.png"></a>
                          </td>
                          <td vAlign="top">
                              <span id="moreInfoContainer"><a href="javascript:expandCollapse('infoBlockID', true);">More information</a></span>
                              <noscript>&lt;ID id="moreInformation"&gt;More information&lt;/ID&gt;</noscript>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </h4>
                <div style="display: none;" id="infoBlockID" class="infoBlock">
                    <p id="errorExplanation">This error (HTTP 400 Bad Request) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the web server, but the webpage could not be found because of a problem with the address.</p>
                    <p id="moreInfoSeeHelp">For more information about HTTP errors, see Help.</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

I hope this helps.
Thanks

Comment: There are several suggestions in the HTML for the error you posted. Have you investigated any of them at all? (Particularly `This error (HTTP 400 Bad Request) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the web server, but the webpage could not be found because of a problem with the address.`

Comment: Good job, wordpress! Do you use some kind of proxy?

Comment: This is what I am trying to understanding what is generating the Google Ad which is some Iframe. It has to be a plugin but unsure. This is where it is pointing to: http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?format=nanxnan&output=html&lmt=1346468062&ea=0&flash=11.2.202.228&....

Answer (score 0):

After doing a Windows GREP, I managed to find the culprit Wordpress plugin. It was 'All in One Adsense and YPN' which makes sense. All is well now. Thanks to those that cared to try to help out.